# How to customize responsive columns and inputs fields in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Main question is how to customize bootstrap responsive css? My code partly works but I can't fix this cases. It's hard to explain so for better understanding I made visualization presented on screenshots.

I posted actual cleaned template code on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PyVc7/1/).

Now when width is more then 1200px columns are ok that mean they are two span6 side by side:
[image]
Between 1200px and 980px display should looks like:
[image]
Less then 979px and more then 768px on first navbar colapse I'd like to have something like that on container center:
[image]
Until next shrinkage below 768px right column has jump to new line and stay there when reducing further to 480px and below. I think that view presented below is ok for mobile devices and better looks in narrow desktops browsers with the exception that when scale both columns are not on center: 
[image]

The smallest width corresponds to my expectations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correct, but you can customise the behavior by using media queries

```
// Landscape phones and down
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }

// Landscape phone to portrait tablet
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

// Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

// Large desktop
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

Maybe you have to overwrite some classes and ids. The responsive information can be found on git:

[responsive.less](https://github.com/twitter/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive.less)

- [responsive-1200px-min.less](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive-1200px-min.less)
- [responsive-767px-max.less](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive-767px-max.less)
- [responsive-768px-979px.less](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive-768px-979px.less)
- [responsive-navbar.less](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive-navbar.less)
- [responsive-utilities.less](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive-utilities.less)

Nevertheless play with these Settings only if you really have to.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I discovered this but I don't know what should be in my case in { ... } I tried all but everything doesn't work.

Comment: take a look at the git files https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive-767px-max.less they show how to do it. Maybe you have to inlcude the changes after @import "bootstrap-responsive"; so they does't get overwritten.

Comment: Helpfull example on github. I checked and css is after @import "bootstrap-responsive";.

Comment: I begin to understand if I can do it based on your hints I close this topic.