# How To Change The Default Width Of Responsive Design In Bootstrap 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

How can I change the default width of a responsive design in bootstrap?

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";
body { padding-top: 60px; }
@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539361/how-to-customize-responsive-columns-and-inputs-fields-in-twitter-bootstrap/10549587#10549587) in addition to that I can recommend:

if you are using less try:

```
// Default 940px grid
// -------------------------
@gridColumns: 12;
@gridColumnWidth: 60px;
@gridGutterWidth: 20px;
@gridRowWidth: (@gridColumns * @gridColumnWidth) + (@gridGutterWidth * (@gridColumns - 1));

// Fluid grid
// -------------------------
@fluidGridColumnWidth: 6.382978723%;
@fluidGridGutterWidth: 2.127659574%;
```

More Variables can be found on [git](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less)

---

if you are using sass try:

```
// Default 940px grid
// -------------------------
$gridColumns: 12;
$gridColumnWidth: 60px;
$gridGutterWidth: 20px;
$gridRowWidth: ($gridColumns * $gridColumnWidth) + ($gridGutterWidth * ($gridColumns - 1));

// Fluid grid
// -------------------------
$fluidGridColumnWidth: 6.382978723%;
$fluidGridGutterWidth: 2.127659574%;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually all fluidGridGutterWidth and ColumnWidth stuff is completely ignored. Can set the stuff wherever I want. Nothing changes at all...

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the grid width and whatever else using their web interface, then simply hit "**Customise and Download**" and you'll have your modified CSS:

## http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

Comment: It is true. You can do everything that you can do with the less variables on their website.  For a detailed explanation of how their variables work, refer to here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823742/how-to-change-default-bootstrap-fluid-grid-12-column-gutter-width